# Simple Python code to assign corresponding letter to number grade

Tags: python, list, comparison

I am trying to write code so a user can input raw data that will pull up a numerical grade from a list, AND pair that numerical value with a letter grade. ie: the fourth grade in the list is 86, so it will PRINT 86 as well as the letter grade B.

Here is what I have so far:

---

```
grades = ['62','68','93','75','89','85']

print grades [3]

def lettergrade (grades):

    if grades >=90:
        print('A')
    elif grades >=80 and grades <90:
        print('B')
    elif grades >=70 and grades <80:
        print('C')
    elif grades >=60 and grades <70:
        print('D')
    else:
        print('F')


print lettergrade (grades)
```

Comment: "Here is what I have so far:" and... ? What does it do, what did you expect it to do?

Comment: you need to indent everything under `def lettergrade(grades) for a start.  Do you have a traceback? show it

Comment: I just indented it for you. Remember that python is tab-aware

Comment: `print('B', grades)`

Comment: You should iterate through the grades list in a for loop and pass each value to lettergrade method

Comment: Unlike a lot of other languages, Python can handle chained comparisons. `grades >=80 and grades <90` can be rewritten as `80 <= grades < 90`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should achieve what you are looking for:

```
grades = [62, 68, 93, 75, 89, 85]


def LetterGrade(grade):

    if grade >= 90:
        result = [grade, 'A']
    elif grade >= 80 and grades < 90:
        result = [grade, 'B']
    elif grade >= 70 and grades < 80:
        result = [grade, 'C']
    elif grade >= 60 and grades < 70:
        result = [grade, 'D']
    else:
        result = [grade, 'F']

    return result

# call LetterGrade for each value in grades array
for grade in grades:
    print(LetterGrade(grade))
```

You needed to loop for each value in the grades array. Also, try to get into the habit of following PEP 8 (Python style guide)

Comment: your code gives wrong output - you have to change either the LetterGrade parameter's name or "if grades >= 90:" to "if grade >= 90:" and of course for the other if conditions.

Comment: @coder good call, I am on mobile, but I went ahead and made that change.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you are experiencing is `grades` contains only Strings. '1' is a String just like 'hello'. In python, Strings will not be equal to numbers, so comparing them will always be false. In addition, you are comparing the entirety of `grades` to a number, which will also evaluate to `false`. The comparison that you are looking for is `if(grades[index]>= 90):` where `index` is whatever index you are looking at.

The `print()` statement inside `lettergrade()` will only print out the grade, so change each print statement to `print('LETTER:' + value).

In addition, the method `lettergrade()` will only print out one thing, so there needs to be a loop to call it multiple times, with multiple values:

```
for value in grades:
    lettergrade(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with indentation, python is a language indented.

Try this:

```
# define lettergrade function
def lettergrade(grades):
    if grades >=90:
        return('A')
    elif grades >=80 and grades <90:
        return('B')
    elif grades >=70 and grades <80:
        return('C')
    elif grades >=60 and grades <70:
        return('D')
    else:
        return('F')

grades = ['62','68','93','75','89','85']

for grade in grades: # iterate in grades    
    # call to lettergrade function -> lettergrade(grade)
    print(grade, ' equivalent ', lettergrade(grade))
```

Comment: It would probably be helpful to OP if you explained why you chose to write this code. Our goal should be to help OP think more like a programmer, not just write code for him/her.

Answer (score 0):

I am confused here, If you want the user input why do you want a list of values then? all you have to do is to wait for user input and check which grade that input belongs too. Please comment If you want some changes!!

```
x = raw_input("Enter Score: ")
score = float(x)
try:
    if grades >=90:
        print('A', score)
    elif grades >=80 and grades <90:
        print('B', score)
    elif grades >=70 and grades <80:
        print('C', score)
    elif grades >=60 and grades <70:
        print('D', score)
    else:
        print('F', score)

except:
    print "Error"
```

Comment: The OP specifically called out using a list of values